# How does energy/momentum/information transferred to carriers?

Tags: momentum, quantum-electrodynamics, information, carrier-particles

The forces , interaction , momentum , information , etc . are transferred through carriers like photons . However , how do the carriers themselves get momentum, information and interactions ? What excite and tells those photons to start the action ?

For an example , two like charged particles brought near repel each other. They send momentum to each other (and thus cause force) by transferring photons , the carriers. However , I am interested in knowing that how do **photon carriers** themselves get momentum and information ? Or what is the mechanism of how carriers themselve get information , **as they are the only carriers?** Or **what transfers information from source to carrier?**

Comment: Mechanism? Quantum field theory specifies the details quantitatively, and stunningly accurately. You want a ghost behind the machine?

Comment: Hi Cosmas . What I want is an explanation .

Comment: QM fails to explain things--this is actually a dirty word asking for trouble. It describes things accurately and quantitatively. It has rules for what cannot or can happen. Anything which can happen, does so with some computable probability: one is *never* sure!

Comment: Yes . I get it .

Answer (score 1):

> The forces , interaction , momentum , information , etc . are transferred through carriers like photons .

[This is the lowest order](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) Feynman diagram for the interaction of two electrons It allows us to calculate the probability of scattering between two electrons, given the initial conditions.

[image: ee scatter]

What you call "carriers like photons" is the virtual photon exchanged between incoming and outgoing lines. Virtual lines have the quantum numbers of their name, but their [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) does not have the real mass, in this case zero for an on mass shell photon. The mass of the virtual particle can vary continuously between the limits of integration of the Feynman integral.

One has to study field theory and Feynman diagrams to be able to understand how interactions of quantum entities can be described and predicted  by the theory.

Comment: Thanks Mam . I am sorry but I want to reconfirm: Does quantum physics explain that how interaction is passed over the source and virtual particles?

Comment: QFT models mathematically the interactions, it is good in fitting measurements and predicting new effects successfully. information is a second level that has to use QFT  interactions to be transfered.

Comment: Thanks . I understand that the answer is that we understand that how it happens and it matches experiment . But we don't know about why it happens .

Comment: The why things happen is not a  question answered with theories of physics. The theories tell us **how* using our axioms( laws , principles, postulates derived from observations ) and mathematics,   something happens. The why is metaphysics. we can answer why with because that is what fits the data and observations, circular.

Comment: Thanks mam . I think I now get it. It's related to metaphysics and not physics

Answer (score 1):

Technically, if you want to talk about a photon properly, then you have to assume that an irreversible energy transfer between the electromagnetic quantum field and an external system has taken place. This is the quantum field theoretical equivalent of the Born rule. "The photon" is the amount of energy, momentum and angular momentum that the field has gained or lost in an emission or absorption process. In non-relativistic quantum theory "emission" is usually called "preparation" and "absorption" is called "measurement". The terminology is a little different, but the phenomenology and the structure of the theory is essentially the same.

After an emission process has taken place we can then say that the freely propagating field carries that amount of energy, momentum and angular momentum of the photon with it. These system properties are, however, not localized. They belong to the field as a whole and we can "absorb" them from the field in many different (and non-equivalent) ways in form of an absorbed photon.

Where it gets complicated is the question whether that "emitted photon" is the same as the "absorbed photon" (hint: in general it's not) and if that makes photons behave like atomistic (corpuscular) constituents of the free field. That depends on the level of your description of the field. If you are happy with the description of classical optical phenomena that can be explained with "photon counting" or a corpuscular theory of light, then by all means, think of the photon as an atomistic piece of the field that "carries" energy, momentum and angular momentum. Nothing bad will happen to you in this approximation.

What you can not expect is that this naive intuition will carry through to the realm of actual quantum effects. Just like in non-relativistic quantum theory the "free field" is in a superposition of all possible fields and that state can not be described by a finite number of object-like photons. In general it is therefor not good practice to imagine that an electromagnetic field is just a collection of photons. It does not behave at all like one.